# Selenium issue: UnreachableBrowserException for driver.get().manage().getCookieNamed("JSESSIONID")

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to capture JSESSION ID in  `@beforeClass`

```
Cookie oldCookie = 
driver.get().manage().getCookieNamed("JSESSIONID");
ConsoleLog.info("COOKIE VALUE = " + 
oldCookie.getValue());
```

but the script is failing with

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserExcepti>on: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may >have died.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of driver (chromedriver/geckodriver)?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated gson version and the issue is fixed

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```